# python extract a file with the given regex format

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to extract the file which contains EOB_FILE

for example I have something like

```
s = "path Omega/CC/Pune/SYNTT/EOB_PROCESSED_BY_OCR/EOB_FILE/0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253/0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253_page1.json"
```

How can I get only the file name which is `0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253_page1.json`

Code I tried :

```
val = re.findall(r'([^.]*EOB_FILE[^.]*)', s)
val
['path Omega/CC/Pune/SYNTT/EOB_PROCESSED_BY_OCR/EOB_FILE/0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253/0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253_page1']
```

Output expected :

`0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253_page1.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib):

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(s).name
```

output:

```
'0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253_page1.json'
```

to check if `EOB_FILE` is in the path you could use:

```
'EOB_FILE' in Path(s).parts
```

or:

```
'EOB_FILE' in s
```

---

```
if 'EOB_FILE' in s:
    val = Path(s).name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
s = "path Omega/CC/Pune/SYNTT/EOB_PROCESSED_BY_OCR/EOB_FILE/0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253/0A225618045646F2AEEFC23E74CAC253_page1.json"

os.path.basename(s)
```

os is python miscellaneous operating system interfaces. Check documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)